# Evaluating $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sin(kx)$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\cos(kx)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation, power-series, trigonometric-series

> Playing with sines I wanted to find
>   $$
> S(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sin(kx)
> $$

Writing it as
$$
S(x)=\mathrm{Im}\big(A(x)\big),\quad\text{where}\quad A(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{ikx}
$$
and using $z=e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, cheating about $\|z\|=1$ in order to write
$$
A(x)=\frac{1}{1-z},
$$

I found that

> $$
> 2S(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}
> $$

as WolframAlpha does.

> My question is: why with the same method I found
>   $$
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty\cos(kx)=\frac{1}{2}
> $$
>   while WolframAlpha and G.H.Hardy on the book "Divergent Series" (pg. 2) give $-1/2$?

Comment: Wolfram Alfa gives: `1/2` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk no $-1/2$.

Comment: Put to Wolfram Alfa my code: `Sum[Cos[k x], {k, 0, Infinity}]` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk nice! thanks. try sum cos(kx)

Answer (score 4):

Actually:

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\cos(kx)=\frac{1}{2}+(\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\cos(kx))=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\delta_{0}$ in the Fourier-Stieltjes sense (as distributions for example), while

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sin(kx)$~$\frac{1}{2}\cot{\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}$ in the sense of generalized Fourier sine series

(this means that while $f$ is not necessarily in $L^1(0, \pi)$  so by odd extension it would have a unique sine series if it were integrable, $f\sin nx$ is integrable for every $n \ge 1$ and then we can compute the corresponding integrals $\pi a_n=2\int_0^{\pi}f(x)\sin nx dx$ and write $f$ ~$\sum {a_n \sin nx}$)

both quite legitimate ways of thinking about this

Answer (score 2):

Since, in general, we dont have $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sin(kx)=0$, the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sin(kx)$ diverges (in other words, the sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sin(kx)$ does not exist), and so does the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\cos(kx)$.

Comment: +1. In other words: the sum **DOES NOT EXIST**. Period. Can't be stressed enough, with all those popular videos around encouraging people to assign some arbitrary values to them.

Comment: @TheVee Would you mind if I add to my answer that the sum does not exist?

Comment: Of course not, go ahead :-)

Comment: The "does not exist. Period." claim is slightly too strong. The sine series _does_ exist when $x$ is some integer multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: as noted in my answer both series of the OP make sense in some context (one as the Fourier-Stieltjes series of a measure, the other as a generalized Fourier sine series) - this obviously doesn't mean convergence and not necessarily summability either, though here Abel summability works as the two series come from radial limits of analytic functions on the disc